# Why does Table behave differently in Mathematica compared to WolframCloud?

Tags: list-manipulation, documentation, compatibility

In Stephen Wolfram's elementary introduction to the wolfram language it says you can use the table function like this: `Table[5, 10]`, to create a table of the element `5` repeated `10` times. This works in *WolframCloud* but not in *Mathematica*, at least not *Mathematica* on the Raspberry Pi which is the version I use because it's free. Is there a way I can make the `Table` function in *Mathematica* behave the same as in *WolframCloud*? At the moment it's throwing me an error saying `Table::itform : Argument 10 at position 2 does not have the correct for for an iterator`.

Here's Wolfram's introduction: http://wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/06-making-tables.html

Comment: The command Table[5,10] works for me in Mathematica 10.3.1.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Recently this issue has been discovered for several times in this site, because a new syntax of `Table`

> ```
> Table[expr, n]
> ```

is added silently in v10.3 and the corresponding old syntax

> ```
> Table[expr, {imax}]
> ```

is no longer mentioned in the document. (Yeah it still works! ) Just compare the first usage information of `Table` in [v10.3](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/language/v10.3/ref/Table.html) and [v10.2](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/language/v10.2/ref/Table.html) yourself.

Maybe this should be considered as a bug of the document.

---

As mentioned by [george2079](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/2079/george2079) in the comment, the same thing has also happened on `Do`, in **v10.2**.

You may want to check the document of `Do` in [v10.2](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/language/v10.2/ref/Do.html) and [v10.1](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/language/v10.1/ref/Do.html).

Not sure if there're more. BTW, this does **not** happen on `ParallelTable` and `ParallelDo`.

---

**Update**

The syntax change of `Table` and `Do` has now been documented in v10.4.

Comment: In my version (V10.0.1 on OS X 10.10.5), `Table[expr, 10]` ("Argument 10 does not have the correct form for an iterator.") Perhaps this was introduced in 10.1, 2 or 3?

Comment: @march You're right, according to the legacy document, it's actually added in v10.3. Thanks for pointing out, edited.

Comment: oh my think of how much code will break if they drop the old syntax.  I see the same change for `Do` by the way. Anywhere else?

Comment: @george2079 And this actually happens in v10.2. So this syntax of `Do` isn't as popular as that of `Table` 囧.