# Use a list with single number for the second input of Table

Tags: functions, list-manipulation

As you see both inputs below give the same results. 
Is there any reason to use `List[3]` instead of just `3` in the first case?

```
Table[1,{3}]
(* {1,1,1} *)

Table[1,3]
(* {1,1,1} *)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're before *v10.3*, then only the first syntax is correct. For more information check:

[Why does Table behave differently in Mathematica compared to WolframCloud?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/103535/1871)

BTW this syntax change causes problem in certain cases:

[Unexpected behaviour from Table[]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124046/1871)