# How to simplify the plot codes or provide a new method to obtain the ideal PDF?

Tags: export, 3d-printing

I want to create two planes in 3D space (looks like the following figure 1). Firstly, I try to use the `ContourPlot3D` and `Polygon`, but both of them will generate some unexpected grid or triangle (looks like the following figure 2) when "save as" or "export" the planes to PDF, so I have to replace these two function with `Line` (looks like the following figure 3), but the codes are long and complicate. Later, I find these codes are regular, so want to simplify them, but this is difficult for me. Hope you can help me simplify the plot codes or provide a new method to obtain the ideal PDF, **Note**: I want to have a **3D vector graphics(PDF is better)**. Thanks.

The parameters of these lines are regular, which looks like the following:

```
x = 0;
y = 10;
Graphics3D[{
  Thickness[0.002], Black, Line[{{x, -y, 0}, {x, y, 0}}],
  Thickness[0.002], Black, Line[{{x, -y, 80}, {x, y, 80}}],
  Thickness[0.002], Black, Line[{{x, y, 0}, {x, y, 80}}],
  Thickness[0.002], Black, Line[{{x, -y, 0}, {x, -y, 80}}],
  Thickness[0.002], Black, Line[{{-y, x, 0}, {y, x, 0}}],
  Thickness[0.002], Black, Line[{{-y, x, 80}, {y, x, 80}}],
  Thickness[0.002], Black, Line[{{y, x, 0}, {y, x, 80}}],
  Thickness[0.002], Black, Line[{{-y, x, 0}, {-y, x, 80}}]
  }, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

How to simplify them. Thanks!

Here are the codes of other two functions

```
sx = 10;
ContourPlot3D[{{x == 0}, {y == 0}}, {x, -sx, sx}, {y, -sx, sx}, {z, 0,
   80}, Mesh -> None, 
 ContourStyle -> {Directive[Blue, Opacity[0.01]], 
   Directive[Red, Opacity[0.01]]}, PlotRange -> All]

Graphics3D[{Thickness[0.002], Black, Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 80}}], 
  Blue, Opacity[.1], 
  Polygon[{{-sx, 0, 0}, {sx, 0, 0}, {sx, 0, 80}, {-sx, 0, 80}}], Red, 
  Opacity[.1], 
  Polygon[{{0, -sx, 0}, {0, sx, 0}, {0, sx, 80}, {0, -sx, 80}}]}, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

Figure 1

[image]

Figure 2

[image]

Figure 3

[image]

Comment: The question is unclear to me. What's the input here? What are `f` and `expr`? Are you looking for something like `func[x_, y_]={{x, y, 30}, {-x, -y, 30}, {y, x, 30}, {-y, -x, 30}}; func[1, 2]`?

Comment: OK, so you've over-simplified the question. Then, have you tried `Hyperplane` or `InfinitePlane`?

Comment: @xzczd, the two functions you mentioned are introduced after the Mathematica version 10, however, they can not "save as" or "export"  3D vector graphics after the version 9.0. Can you provide me another solution? Thanks.

Comment: …Do you mean you're in _v9_? If so, please mention this in the question.

Comment: Just tested in _v9_, Win10, the following works well: `Export["a.pdf", 
  ContourPlot3D[{x == 0, y == 0}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10}, Mesh -> None,
    ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.1], Ticks -> None]] // SystemOpen` I guess you didn't add `Mesh->None`?

Comment: @xzczd, There is no restriction on the Mathematica version. I only want to get a vector graphics.

Comment: @xzczd, so many times, I have tested this function you mentioned on different version. V8, V9 gave large unexpected triangle and grid (can find them in AI or Inkscape), and V10, V11.3 failed to give a vector graphics.

Comment: Have you explicitly set `"AllowRasterization"` to `False` when exporting? Also, which version of Inkscape are you using? I just checked the output of `Export["a.pdf", 
 ContourPlot3D[{x == 0, y == 0}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10}, Mesh -> None, 
  ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.1], Ticks -> None], "AllowRasterization" -> False]` using _v9.0.1_ in Inkscape 1.0, the result looks fine.

Comment: @xzczd, Thanks, unexpected elements exactly can not be seen in Inkscape 1.0. but they exist in fact( you can ungroup the figure and double click these triangles on any planes in Inkscape 1.0), and they can be found in adobe acrobat and Adobe illustrator.

Comment: Oh I forgot I've put [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14759/1871) in my init.m file…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `AnglePath`?:

```
pts = AnglePath[{1/2, -1/2}, Table[90 °, 4]];

{{#, 0, #2} & @@@ pts, {0, #, #2} & @@@ pts} // Line // Graphics3D
```

---

Since there's a [design change for export of `Graphics3D[…]` to PDF format](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92133/1871) after *v9* and it seems to be hard to bring back the old behavior in newer versions, I think the easiest work-around is to stay in *v9* and implement `AnglePath` ourselves. Luckily J.M. has already implemented it [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/89041/1871). So we just need to modify the code to:

```
pts = anglePath[{1/2, -1/2}, Table[90 °, {4}]];

{{#, 0, #2} & @@@ pts, {0, #, #2} & @@@ pts} // Line // Graphics3D
```

Notice I've modified the syntax of `Table`, you may check [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/103539/1871) for more info about the syntax change.

Comment: Thanks. It's become concise exactly, but if you noticed that it fails to generate vector graphics.

Comment: @likehust Then I believe your approach won't generate vector graphics, either, because it's a combination of `Graphics3D` and `Line`, just like mine. Can you clarify the meaning of "vector graphics" in your mind?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. the vector graphics I want is same as [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics), the `AnglePath` is introduced on version 10, so it can not "save as" or "export" to a 3D vector graphics(but can generate 2D vector graphics), and I have tested the result.

Comment: @likehust "the AnglePath is introduced on version 10, so it can not "save as" or "export" to a 3D vector graphics(but can generate 2D vector graphics" I don't understand what you mean. The output of `AnglePath` is just a list of numbers whose dimension is $n×2$, and I've transformed it to a $n×3$ list with `{#, 0, #2} & @@@`. The output of my code is undoubtedly 3D vector grahpic. Have you tried my code?

Comment: From V10, the exported 3D PDF graphics are bitmaps, but 2D PDF graphics are vectors. Maybe the V9 is the final version that can "save graphic as" and "export"  3D and 2D PDF vector graphics at the same time. So, `AnglePath` , introduced on V10.1 in 2015, can not generate 3D PDF vector graphics, it only can obtain bitmap figure when export or save graphic as. I have tested your code, thanks.

Comment: @likehust I guess I know what you mean. You mean the issue mentioned here, right: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92133/1871 I've added a solution work in _v9_, check my update.

Comment: The method you mentioned in the [reference](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92133/1871) will be invalid after the option `Opacity` being inserted. I will use the method replacing plane with line, and take your solution. If, someday, you have a better method, paste here please. Thank you again.

Answer (score 3):

```
f[x_, y_] := {{x, y, 30}, {-x, -y, 30}, {y, x, 30}, {-y, -x, 30}}

x = 1;
y = 2;

Apply[f, List[x, y]]
```

> {{1, 2, 30}, {-1, -2, 30}, {2, 1, 30}, {-2, -1, 30}}

Comment: Sorry, I didn't propose a clear question. But, you can proceed to give a better solution. Thanks.